# Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/courts/by_coordinates/41.89400864"

Tags: ruby, api, rails-geocoder

I have this error when I try to search in url by coordinates (saved as :latitude and :longitude in db using geocoder gem):
**No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/courts/by_coordinates/41.89400864"**
Here the code that I'm using.

```
module API
  module V1
    class Courts < Grape::API
      version 'v1' # path-based versioning by default
      format :json # We don't like xml anymore

      resource :courts do

        desc "Courts index"
        get do
          courts = Court.all
          present courts, with: API::Entities::Court
        end

        desc "Search by address or city"
        params do
          requires :address, :type => String, :desc => "Court Address"
        end
        get "by_address/:address" do
          courts = Court.near(params[:address])
          present courts, with: API::Entities::Court
        end

        desc "Search by address or city and range"
        params do
          requires :address, :type => String, :desc => "Court Address"
          requires :distance, :type => Integer, :desc => "Range of Distance"
        end
        get "by_address/:address/:distance" do
          courts = Court.near(params[:address], params[:distance])
          present courts.sort_by(&:distance), with: API::Entities::Court
        end

        desc "Search by coordinates"
        params do
          requires :latitude, :type => BigDecimal, :desc => "Court Latitude"
        end
        get "by_coordinates/:latitude" do
          courts = Court.near(params[:latitude])
          present courts, with: API::Entities::Court
        end

      end

    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand why if I use the research by address it works, but if I simply change the address with latitude params it stops to work.
Someone can halp me, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like a bug when using `BigDecimal` as type, that was solved in grape 1.3.1 https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md, which version are you using?

Comment: Ok, I'm using grape 1.2.3, so do you suggest to upgrade to grape 1.3.1?

Comment: maybe you can try using a different type and see if that solves the problem... a gem upgrade might bring other issues if you don't have enough test coverage

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help!